# Unknow option javacomplete#complete when using vim to edit java files

Tags: linux, vim, vim-plugin

I have set omnifuc in my .vimrc file :

```
setlocal omnifunc = javacomplete#complete
```

Then the exception comes out when i editing any file :

```
E518: Unknown option: javacomplete#complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after the `=`.  With this space vim is interpreting the `javacomplete#complete` as a vim option.

Here is an excerpt from vim's help on `:set-args`:

```
:se[t] {option}={value}

                           ...

                           White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and
                           will be ignored.  White space between '=' and {value}
                           is not allowed.
```